# Which path can i use inside my program that will fit other computers? (that also have ubuntu)

Tags: linux, qt, path

I made a program in QT c++ that creates some files and i want them to be saved in a specific directory, i created a directory and i moved all the program there so i can use that same directory to save them, but when i write the path to save the files i have to write:

`/home/"the name of my computer"/my_program/file.txt`

and i want to use this same program in different computers. I also tried just writing:

`my_program/file.txt`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: You may want to start with http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html#homePath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relative path approach was already good, but a relative path is treated as relative to the working directory of the process and that depends on how the program is started.

E.g. if you start it from a shell, then the shell's current working directory will be the program's, if you start it from a launcher menu, it is often the user's home directory, but could be the location of the binary, etc.

So it is better to create a path based on well known base paths. such as the user's home directory, see `QDir::home()` or the a common location depending on type of data, see `QStandardPaths`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try home directory path with "~/", many applications save their settings in ~/.applicationName directory